# How excel insert data by vertical extending in C#

Tags: c#

Here is a excel data like :

```
+-------+
| A,B   |
| a1,b1 |
| a2,b2 |
| a3,b3 |
+-------+
```

i expect using Somemethod by epplus `insert data by vertical extending`.
e.g : insert `test` to column `A` and rowindex `2`

```
worksheet.Somemethod(value:"test",location:"A2");
```

and get below data :

```
+---------+
| A,B     |
| a1,b1   |
| test,b2 |
| a2,b3   |
| a3,     |
+---------+
```

i have tried `InsertRow` method of epplus,and i'll get the below result that not my expection :

```
ExcelWorksheet ws = ...;
worksheet.InsertRow(2,1);
Worksheet.Cells[2,1].Value="test";
```

```
+---------+
| A,B     |
| a1,b1   |
| test,   |
| a2,b2   |
| a3,b3   |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after few days searching for docs,i have sloved my question :

1. epplus not support (if it's wrong,please tell me)
2. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 's `Range.Insert` method support it,but it depend on the Microsoft Office lib,so i exclude it.

```
    Excel.Range insertRange = xlWs.Range["A1"];
    insertRange.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
```

3. the best answer for me now is `CloseXML`,below is my answer code :

```
void Main()
{
    var wb = new XLWorkbook();
    var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    var table = new DataTable();
    {
        table.Columns.Add("A", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("B", typeof(string));
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            table.Rows.Add($"a{i}", $"b{i}");
    }
    var rangeWithData = ws.Cell(1, 1).InsertData(table.AsEnumerable());

    //insert data by vertical extending
    {
        var cell = ws.Range("A1").InsertRowsBelow(1).First();
        cell.Value = "test";
    }

    var path = $"{Path.GetTempPath()}{Guid.NewGuid()}.xlsx";
    wb.SaveAs(path);
    Process.Start(path);
}
```

[image]